# iOS 8 Auto layout uiimage resize issue

Tags: ios, autolayout, ios8, xcode6, autoresize

I have added

```
 trailing space = 0  
 Leading Space  >= 100   
 Bottom Space = 0  
 Top Space = 0
```

[image]

All the above mentioned auto-layout constraints has beed added to the grey coloured imageview, and imageview content mode is set to AspectFit. How can i remove leading and trailing grey space from the imageview. I want to keep the content mode as AscpectFit.

Comment: need to image mode.. or set imageview bgcolor clearcolor

Comment: @preetam I have added a grey background color for identify the UIImageView. How can i move UIImage's edge(Not UIImageView's edge) to the right side of the superview ?

Comment: reduce the imageview width, make same as image and then adjust

Comment: @preetam I think you dont have enough knowledge about autolayout. Please dont come up with silly answers, its really annoying.

Comment: ok...then search and also post yourself...so that I can learn from you @appleBump..

Comment: @applebumb: I am waiting for your answer

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This cannot be done through storyboard. Interface Builder cannot do everything. It only provides a limited selection of constraints. For example, there is no way to create a constraint that keeps the aspect ratio of a view – how wide versus how high the view is – the same at all times. But still you can achieve this through programmatically. 
e.g. button1.width = button1.height * ratio.